# Fetch all values from all granules of an ImageMosaic click event

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, time-series, image-mosaic

I have sucessfully implemented a time series for an ImageMosaic in OpenLayers, using Geoserver as my processing tool. Additionally, I have implemented an onClick event to fetch values when a user clicks on a pixel.

However, I would like to know whether there is a possibility to fetch all values for a specific coordinate that I clicked. That way for instance, one granule can be visually shown but values should be retrieved from all granules, so I can put them in an array and visualise them as a TimeSeries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GetFeatureInfo on the mosaic layer will just give you the value of the pixel at that point: information about the set of images used to produce it is lost by the time GetFeaureInfo runs.

However, you can publish the image mosaic index as a separate vector layer, and query that one instead.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. In the layer preview of the published mosaic index, if I click on it, I get the names of the geotiffs and their location within a folder - but no pixel values. Is it safe to assume that your answer is a starting point and the rest is left to the developer (which is basically what I asked for, just checking).

Comment: Hum.... you can try to have a second mosaic in "stack" mode (it's one of the read parameters you can configure in the layer page, bottom of first tab). In that case images are not mosaicked, but stacked to create a single image with many bands. I've only used this approach in cases where the number of images is controlled and small, not sure it's a good idea to use it as a general tool (from the p.o.v. of stability and memory usage)

Comment: That is my current solution, but as you can imagine, it is very heavy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use WMTS plugin for this.

https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/wmts-multidimensional/index.html